# How to change commiter author's name in Xcode

Tags: xcode, git, xcode12

Can I change committer author's name in Xcode?
From Xcode in section `Adjust Editor Options` in `Authors` I see *TarasChernysh* and name of commit. So I'd like to use *Taras* instead of *TarasChernysh*. Can you help me?

Comment: Use `git config` to change `user.name`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change this with following command, if *TarasChernysh* is your own git `user.name`:

```
git config --global user.name "Taras"
```

The `--global` will make sure all of your future commits use this given `user.name`. If you will only in the certain repository, then leave `--global` out and the `user.name` changed only for this repository.